# logging session with 'script' - how later read it?

Tags: terminal

I log my terminal session with `script`.

As we know, it contains all characters that were send to terminal, including control ones, like backspaces etc. This makes output file a kind of unreadable, therefore:

What's the best way to later read output of `script`? (so it looks more like terminal after finished session)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
cat script_file
```

Comment: You could also just `cat`. STDOUT should already be connected to the tty.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks. I thought I had tried this and it didn't work for me. Turns out I didn't and it does :)